# Gulp watch mostra muito erros eslint. Quais dependências estão faltando?

Tags: ionic, gulp, eslint

Fiz o git clone de um app **Ionic 1** feito com o [Generator-M-Ionic](https://github.com/mwaylabs/generator-m-ionic)

Fiz os seguintes passos para instalar as dependências:

```
npm install
bower install
npm install --global gulp-cli
```

E os prerequisitos do próprio gerador:

```
npm i -g yo gulp bower
npm i -g generator-m-ionic
```

Após isso o comando

```
gulp watch
```

O terminal executa normal

```
[13:58:09] Starting 'jsonlint'...
[13:58:10] Finished 'watch' after 191 ms
[Browsersync] Access URLs:
 ----------------------------------------
       Local: http://localhost:3000
    External: http://192.168.100.235:3000
 ----------------------------------------
          UI: http://localhost:3001
 UI External: http://192.168.100.235:3001
 ----------------------------------------
[Browsersync] Serving files from: app
[Browsersync] Serving files from: .tmp
[13:58:10] Finished 'jsonlint' after 488 ms
```

Mas váários erros como esse abaixo aparecem em seguida no terminal e meu navegador só abre uma tela vazia.

```
app/main/controllers/logoutCtrl.js
   2:1   error    "SocialWaveApp" is not defined          no-undef
   3:3   warning  Unexpected console statement            no-console
   4:3   error    "mixpanel" is not defined               no-undef
   8:9   error    "hideSheet" is defined but never used   no-unused-vars
  13:32  error    "index" is defined but never used       no-unused-vars
  17:9   error    "mixpanel" is not defined               no-undef
  22:9   warning  Unexpected console statement            no-console
  30:11  error    "facebookConnectPlugin" is not defined  no-undef
  34:13  warning  Unexpected console statement            no-console
```

**Como descobrir quais são as dependências e o que está faltando?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

O problema era com algumas dependências, como fserve que só roda no Mac, então a solução foi passar a usar um macbook, agora o aplicativo funciona.

Os erros eslint mostram apenas que meu projeto não está usando as boas práticas do  JavaScript.